# setting cookie for use in warden. "invalid cookie value"

Tags: ruby, cookies

I am writing specs for my api and am manually writing a http request.

I am trying to set a cookie by adding the following key-val header

cookies

```
cookies: {
        'warden.user.user.key' => ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(
          [[session_data[0]], session_data[1]]
        )
      }
```

That's a String-String key-val pair, but the value is invalid. I get `ArgumentError: Invalid cookie value` for the JSON-serialized value (which ends up as

```
"\"[[Xy2LppWrQ53yHmpxVOkF7w], $2a$10$a/kS05VaSlNv2wwBXPfGU.]\""
```

I honestly have no idea how to fix this. I am trying to make a cookie with this format because in my Controller, I figured out that the session cookie is stored in `warden.user.user.key` and the value is a nested array of `[[object_uid], session_token]`

Appreciate whatever help! thanks

If it makes any difference, I am using [airborne](https://github.com/brooklynDev/airborne) to make the requests (which uses rest-client under the hood, but doesn't throw errors on non-OK status codes.)

In the bigger picture I'm just trying to pass a session token to warden, which is used by devise.